# Can not import functions corretly in reactJS App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I am having problem with `import`, I have a file like this :

```
import { TYPE_CONTRAT_UPDATE, CONFORMITE_UPDATE } from "./actionsTypes";

import { createAction } from "../../../../../../redux/Utilities";

const updateTypeContrat = (idContrat, data, success, error) =>
    createAction(TYPE_CONTRAT_UPDATE.PUT_CALL, { idContrat, data, success, 
error });
const updateConformiteContrat = (idContrat, data, success, error) => 
    createAction(CONFORMITE_UPDATE.PUT_CALL, { idContrat, data, success, 
error });
export default { updateTypeContrat, updateConformiteContrat};
```

I am trying to import as you can see variables in capital from my file actionsTypes, here is the file :

```
import { createPutTypes } from "../../../../../../redux/Utilities";

const TYPE_CONTRAT_UPDATE = createPutTypes("TYPE_CONTRAT_UPDATE");
const CONFORMITE_UPDATE = createPutTypes("CONFORMITE_UPDATE");

export default { CONFORMITE_UPDATE, TYPE_CONTRAT_UPDATE }
```

But I get an error :

> Line 1:  TYPE_CONTRAT_UPDATE not found in './actionsTypes'  import/named
>      Line 1:  CONFORMITE_UPDATE not found in './actionsTypes'    import/named

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use named export instead of the default.

```
import { createPutTypes } from "../../../../../../redux/Utilities";

export const TYPE_CONTRAT_UPDATE = createPutTypes("TYPE_CONTRAT_UPDATE");
export const CONFORMITE_UPDATE = createPutTypes("CONFORMITE_UPDATE");
```

Comment: I am using Eslint, when I use named export I get an error telling me 'prefer default export' .. I need to fix the problem using default exporting and importing, thanks for your time sir

Comment: That error happens when you've got only one named export. Is the code working with named exports?

Answer (score 1):

Those imports, as said from the error, should be `named exports`.

#### DEFAULT export

A default export (`export default [...]` is what will be imported when using `import X from 'fileX'`. There can be only one. No matter what you assign the import to in this case (here, you assign it to X), it will work

```
// fileX.js
export default Example;
```

You can do either

```
import X from 'fileX'; // works, X contains Example
import Example from 'fileX'; // same
...
```

#### NAMED exports

A named export (`export const TYPE_CONTRACT = [...]`) can be used as much as you want, however, the name of the import matters:

```
// fileX.js 
export const Example = [...]
```

means that the import should be :

```
import { Example } from 'fileX'; // works properly, Example contains the export of fileX
import { X } from 'fileX'; // won't work, no way to know which export you're referring to
import Example from 'fileX'; // won't work either, this is not a default export.
```